# Forms Designer Error Display HTML Source

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I i am unable to see the design view of a winform app

**Errors are:**

> One or more errors encountered while
>   loading the designer. The errors are
>   listed below. Some errors can be fixed
>   by rebuilding your project, while
>   others may require code changes.
>
> The event Click is read-only and
>   cannot be changed.
>
> at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.EventBindingService.EventPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object
>   component, Object value)
>
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAttachEventStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeAttachEventStatement
>   statement)
>
> at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeStatement statement)

Comment: There is something in designer code causing an error.  Does this form have a custom control inside it?

Comment: So whats the question?  Any errors?

Comment: Have you inherited a form from another base form?

Comment: @m.edmondson: the errors were hidden in the block of html text.  See edited version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following helpful links:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/329327/designer-error-when-implementing-a-baseform-event-for-a-control-on-an-inherited-form

http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=1075&q=the+event+click+is+read-only+and+cannot+be+changed&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=

Of course, I'm only guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the default in the form designer is to make these Friendly or Private.  You need these to be protected or internal. You can just change this and the designer will not overwrite this change.